# How to randomly sample dataframe rows with unique column values

Tags: r, random, dataframe

The ultimate objective is to compare the variance and standard deviation of a  simple statistic (numerator / denominator / true_count) from the `avg_score` for 10 trials of incrementally sized random samples per word from a dataset similar to:

```
library (data.table)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  word_ID = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),rep(4,5),rep(5,5),rep(6,3),rep(7,4),rep(8,4),rep(9,6),rep(10,4)),
  word = c(rep("cat",4), rep("house", 3), rep("sung",2), rep("door",5), rep("pretty", 5), rep("towel",3), rep("car",4), rep("island",4), rep("ran",6), rep("pizza", 4)), 
  true_count = c(rep(234,4),rep(39,3),rep(876,2),rep(4,5),rep(67,5),rep(81,3),rep(90,4),rep(43,4),rep(54,6),rep(53,4)),
  occurrences = c(rep(234,4),rep(34,3),rep(876,2),rep(4,5),rep(65,5),rep(81,3),rep(90,4),rep(43,4),rep(54,6),rep(51,4)),
  item_score = runif(40),
  avg_score = rnorm(40),
  line = c(71,234,71,34,25,32,573,3,673,899,904,2,4,55,55,1003,100,432,100,29,87,326,413,32,54,523,87,988,988,12,24,754,987,12,4276,987,93,65,45,49),
  validity = sample(c("T", "F"), 40, replace = T)

)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[ , denominator := 1:.N, by=word_ID]
dt[ , numerator := 1:.N, by=c("word_ID", "validity")]
dt$numerator[df$validity=="F"] <- 0
df <- dt

<df
    word_ID  word  true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score line validity denominator numerator
 1:       1    cat        234         234 0.25497614  0.15268651   71        F           1         0
 2:       1    cat        234         234 0.18662407  1.77376261  234        F           2         0
 3:       1    cat        234         234 0.74554352 -0.64807093   71        T           3         1
 4:       1    cat        234         234 0.93296878 -0.19981748   34        T           4         2
 5:       2  house         39          34 0.49471189  0.68924373   25        F           1         0
 6:       2  house         39          34 0.64499368  0.03614551   32        T           2         1
 7:       2  house         39          34 0.17580259  1.94353631  573        F           3         0
 8:       3   sung        876         876 0.60299465  0.73721373    3        T           1         1
 9:       3   sung        876         876 0.88775767  2.32133393  673        F           2         0
10:       4   door          4           4 0.49020940  0.34890935  899        T           1         1
11:       4   door          4           4 0.01838357 -1.13391666  904        T           2         2
```

The data represents each detection of a word in a document, so it's possible for a word to appear on the same line more than once. The task is for the sample size to represent unique column values (`line`), but to return all instances where the line number is the same- meaning the actual number of rows returned could be more than the specified sample size. So, for one two-word sample size trial for "cat", the form of the desired result would be:

```
    word_ID  word  true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score line validity denominator numerator
 1:       1    cat        234         234 0.25497614  0.15268651   71        F           1         0
 2:       1    cat        234         234 0.18662407  1.77376261  234        F           2         0
 3:       1    cat        234         234 0.74554352 -0.64807093   71        T           3         1
```

My basic iteration (found on this site) currently looks like:

```
for (i in 1:10) {

  a2[[i]] <- lapply(split(df, df$word_ID), function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 2, replace = T), ])

  b3[[i]] <- lapply(split(df, df$word_ID), function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 3, replace = T), ])}

}
```

So, I can do the standard random sample sizes, but am unsure (and couldn't find something similar or wasn't looking the right way) how to approach the goal stated above. Is there a straight-forward way to approach this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution that uses a join on a sampled data.table.

```
set.seed(1234)
df[df[, .(line=sample(unique(line), 2)), by=word], on=.(word, line)]
```

The inner data.table consists of two columns, word and line, and has two rows per word, each with a unique value for line. The values for line are returned by `sample` which is fed the unique values of line and is performed separately for each word (using `by=word`). You can vary the number of unique line values by changing 2 to your desired value. This data.table is joined onto the main data.table in order to select the desired rows.

In this instance, you get

```
    word_ID   word true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score line validity
 1:       1    cat        234         234 0.26550866  0.91897737   71        F
 2:       1    cat        234         234 0.57285336  0.07456498   71        T
 3:       1    cat        234         234 0.37212390  0.78213630  234        T
 4:       2  house         39          34 0.89838968 -0.05612874   32        T
 5:       2  house         39          34 0.94467527 -0.15579551  573        F
 6:       3   sung        876         876 0.62911404 -0.47815006  673        T
 7:       3   sung        876         876 0.66079779 -1.47075238    3        T
 8:       4   door          4           4 0.06178627  0.41794156  899        F
 9:       4   door          4           4 0.38410372 -0.05380504   55        F
10:       5 pretty         67          65 0.71761851 -0.39428995  100        F
11:       5 pretty         67          65 0.38003518  1.10002537  100        F
12:       5 pretty         67          65 0.49769924 -0.41499456 1003        F
13:       6  towel         81          81 0.21214252 -0.25336168  326        F
14:       6  towel         81          81 0.93470523 -0.16452360   87        F
15:       7    car         90          90 0.12555510  0.55666320   32        T
16:       7    car         90          90 0.26722067 -0.68875569   54        F
17:       8 island         43          43 0.01339033  0.36458196   87        T
18:       8 island         43          43 0.38238796  0.76853292  988        F
19:       8 island         43          43 0.86969085 -0.11234621  988        T
20:       9    ran         54          54 0.59956583 -0.61202639  754        F
21:       9    ran         54          54 0.82737332  1.43302370 4276        F
22:      10  pizza         53          51 0.79423986 -0.36722148   93        F
23:      10  pizza         53          51 0.41127443 -0.13505460   49        T
    word_ID   word true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score line validity
```

Comment: 47 seconds ... but since mine is base and yours is `data.table`, I'll keep my answer as a complement.

Comment: These look like pretty distinct methods and the more base answers, the better.

Comment: I've been meaning to learn `data.table`. I learn well when I see base (which I recognize) paired with analogous non-base solutions. So for me, seeing both is perfectly relevant. Thanks :-)

Comment: I would accept both if I could since they're both very instructive (with great explanations) for me especially in tandem. Is it possible to keep the method this compact, but to only return more rows for a word than the sample size *if* there are duplicate `line` values [not pull them all]? Meaning, sample until there are n rows for a word that have unique `line` values while keeping the samples already pulled. To do so would require a loop, correct? [you both answered my original question, this is just a follow on after seeing the solutions methods]. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you sample from a de-duplicated data.frame and do a subsequent left-join with the original data, you can ensure what you need.

I'm not proficient with `data.table`, so I'll use base functions. (`dplyr` would work well here, too, but since you're using `data.table`, I'll avoid it for now.) (As I'm about to hit submit, @lmo provided a `dt`-specific answer ...)

By "de-duplicate", I mean:

```
subdf <- df[,c("word_ID", "line")]
subdf <- subdf[!duplicated(subdf),]
dim(subdf)
# [1] 36  2
head(subdf)
#   word_ID line
# 1       1   71
# 2       1  234
# 4       1   34
# 5       2   25
# 6       2   32
# 7       2  573
```

Note that the `subdf` only has three rows for 1, whereas the original data has 4:

```
df[1:4,]
#   word_ID word true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score line validity
# 1       1  cat        234         234  0.2655087  0.91897737   71        F
# 2       1  cat        234         234  0.3721239  0.78213630  234        T
# 3       1  cat        234         234  0.5728534  0.07456498   71        T
# 4       1  cat        234         234  0.9082078 -1.98935170   34        T
```

I'm using `by` here instead of `lapply/split`, but the results should be the same:

```
out <- by(subdf, subdf$word_ID, function(x) merge(x[sample(nrow(x), 2, replace=TRUE),], df, by=c("word_ID", "line")))
out[1]
# $`1`
#   word_ID line word true_count occurrences item_score   avg_score validity
# 1       1   34  cat        234         234  0.9082078 -1.98935170        T
# 2       1   71  cat        234         234  0.5728534  0.07456498        T
# 3       1   71  cat        234         234  0.2655087  0.91897737        F
```